# Is there a static code checker for C that would flag a missing mutex unlock?

Tags: c, static, clang, analysis, clang-tidy

In the code below, two threads are working with the same function and each thread is supposed to acquire the lock before starting. So the first thread gets the lock, does the job, and leaves, but without releasing the lock, since the unlock command is deliberately commented out. The second thread never gets the lock and therefore never does the job.

I created this simple example just to test if the static code checker that I am using would flag this situation (missing unlock), and it does not. I am using [CodeChecker](https://github.com/Ericsson/codechecker) which has clang static analyzer and clang-tidy checkers. Do you know of any static code checker that would flag this? I think Coverity might, but I don't have the license to prove it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

pthread_t tid[2];
int counter;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* doSomeThing() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    unsigned long i = 0;
    counter += 1;
    printf("\n Job %d started\n", counter);

    for(i=0; i<(0xFFFFFFF);i++);

    printf("\n Job %d finished\n", counter);

    // pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(i < 2) {
        err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
        i++;
    }

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think HPfortify does.

Comment: Here is the list of Alternatives to [Coverity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238149/any-alternative-to-coverity-on-jenkins)

Answer (score 1):

Coverity can show defects from semaphore locks/unlocks combination with the `--concurrency` option.

See this [article](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Coverity-to-catch-locks-unlocks) for additional details.